# How to submit new version of my app which is not compatible with older versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

An old app I submitted was compatible with iOS 3.1.3. I don't want to support older versions anymore, and only want to support iOS 6.0 and above.

Should I just submit the new version, and change the deployment target to 6.0 ?

Is that enough ? What do I need to do to make sure that Apple does not reject it because it is not compatible with older devices anymore ?

Comment: When you submit an app, it is up to you as to what versions of iOS you support.  You can submit an app that only supports iOS 9 if you want.

Comment: @Paulw11 - The app is already in the store. I want to submit an update which does not support earlier versions of iOS(3.1.3), but only supports versions 6 and greater.

Comment: That is fine. Apple doesn't require you to support old iOS versions forever (or indeed at all)

Comment: @Paulw11not sure if it was like that back then but for anyone reading this now, it is now...

Answer (score 1):

Following Steps may help you.

1. Change the Deployment Target to iOS 6.
2. Test your code/app in Xcode 7 or above.
3. Fix the issues as there may be some deprecated methods or frameworks used in app.

Very Important- You will have to do conditional Coding in case of Deprecated Methods/Frameworks.

If everything is fine go ahead for App Store deployment.

Thanks & Regards,

Amit K.